# mysql8 function index not work with reverse() like '%abc'

Tags: mysql, function, indexing, reverse

I have a mysql8 database for develop, with a table name `xxx`, have one comlum name `serial_number`, varchar(10), with many rows.

column serial_number value like:

```
'abc1k3', 
'dfe324', 
'fg23xy',
'hgfdsy',
......
```

I want search which one row end of 'abc', but

```
like '%abc'
```

is very slow,

so I create a function index use reverse function

```
ALTER TABLE `xxx` 
ADD  INDEX `ridx_serial_number` ((reverse(`serial_number`)));
```

but sql below not work on this index

```
select * from xxx where reverse(serial_number) like 'cba%';
```

or

```
select * from xxx USE INDEX(ridx_serial_number) where reverse(serial_number) like 'cba%';
```

Execute plan show it still use full table scan.

and I don't want create new redundant column, auto correlation with reverse(serial_number). Although this can also solve the problem, it introduces complexity

can somebody help? thanks

Comment: ??The Alter statement will not syntax,

Comment: @P.Salmon It's allowed in MySQL 8.0.13.

Comment: Have you tried adding a virtual column?

Comment: @P.Salmon - needs that 'extra' set of parens.

Comment: For me, on 8.0.29, the index is created, but not used.  Suggest filing a bug report at bugs.mysql.com.

Comment: Shouldn't you include a string that does match in your example data?  And please indicate which one(s) you want to match.